# Добавить элемент в начало ArrayList

Tags: java

Хочу отсортировать коллекцию так чтобы вначале были элементы,модуль которых не превышает 1.
Придумал примерно так,но теперь не знаю как реализовать.
откуда брать индекс и где хранить значение

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                if (Math.abs(array.get(индекс)) <= 1) {
                    array.set(0,value);
```

Comment: Сортируйте по модулю весь list и все

Comment: Как это можно сделать? Я недопонял

Comment: Краткое описание не отражает сути задачи. Добавить элемент или сортировать list?

Answer (score 2):

Как то так

```
  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Double>() {
        @Override public int compare(Double p1, Double p2) {
            return Math.abs(p1) - Math.abs( p2); // Ascending
        }
```